# Socket output is not received

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have a Server and a Client classes, the Server and the Client exchange messages between each other. The code is rather silly, made for testing purposes and the way it is supposed to work is the following: when the party (client/server) sends a message, it receives all the messages the other party has sent so far (until the InputStream is empty). The piece of code, implementing this, is located inside Client's while and Server's for loops:

The Client:

```
 public class ClientSocketRunner {
    private static String ip="localhost";
    private static int port=440;
    private static String client="Client";
    private static String server="Server";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        ClientSocketRunner socket_runner=new ClientSocketRunner();
        socket_runner.run();
    }

    private void run() throws Exception
    {
         Socket client_socket=new Socket(ip, port);
        OutputStream os=client_socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is=client_socket.getInputStream();

        PrintStream make_output=new PrintStream(os);
        BufferedReader read_input=new BufferedReader(new                      
         InputStreamReader(is));

        make_output.println("Hello, I'm the Client");
        System.out.println(read_input.readLine());
        System.out.println("my port: "+client_socket.getLocalPort());

       String line=null;
       BufferedReader user_input=new BufferedReader(new 
          InputStreamReader(System.in));
       while (!(line=user_input.readLine()).equals("-1"))
       {
              make_output.println(client+": "+line);
              make_output.flush();
              System.out.println("sent");
               while (is.available()>0)
        {
            System.out.println(read_input.readLine());
        }
              System.out.println("bytes: "+is.available());
       }

        while (is.available()>0)
        {
            System.out.println(read_input.readLine());
        }

    }
```

The Server:

```
public class ServerSocketRunner {
    private static int port=440;
    private static String client="Client";
    private static String server="Server";




    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocketRunner ssRunner=new ServerSocketRunner();
        ssRunner.run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception 
    {

        ServerSocket server_socket=new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket socket=server_socket.accept();
        InputStream sin=socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream sout=socket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedReader read_input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sin));
        PrintStream make_output=new PrintStream(sout);



        System.out.println(read_input.readLine());
        make_output.println("Good to meet you, I'm the Server");
        System.out.println("my port: "+socket.getLocalPort());

        String line;
        BufferedReader user_input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));



        for (line=user_input.readLine(); !(line.equals("-1")); line=user_input.readLine())
            {
               make_output.println(server+": "+line);
               make_output.flush();
               System.out.println("sent");
               while (sin.available()>0)
               {
                  System.out.println(read_input.readLine());
               }
            }

        }

    }
```

But it doesn't work as expected. When I make a multi-line input, it does prints out ("sent") for each line, but when I go to the other party, send some line out the expected input doesn't show up. Until after the next couple of interactions between parties.. 
What is the problem?

Comment: You aren't checking for end stream correctly, so you will get NPEs, and you have classic misuses of `available()`. They are pointless, as they will still block in `readLine()` if a complete line is not available.

Comment: @EJP, So the problem is, I type in too short lines, so they can't be read on the other side? But why doesn't this problem arise when I simply read and display user's input like this: `BufferedReader user_input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` , ` while (!(line=user_input.readLine()).equals("-1"))`, `System.out.println("User: "+line);`? Even the shortest lines are displayed correctly and immediately.

Comment: No. I haven't said what the problem is. I have *commented* that you are calling `available()` pointlessly. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

actually this code runs as expected

but if you want , for example, server immediately displays client's input use this
code:

```
public class ServerSocketRunner {
    private static int port=440;
    private static String client="Client";
    private static String server="Server";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ServerSocketRunner ssRunner=new ServerSocketRunner();
    ssRunner.run();
}

public void run() throws Exception 
{

    ServerSocket server_socket=new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket socket=server_socket.accept();
    InputStream sin=socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream sout=socket.getOutputStream();
    BufferedReader read_input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sin));
    PrintStream make_output=new PrintStream(sout);

    System.out.println(read_input.readLine());
    make_output.println("Good to meet you, I'm the Server");
    System.out.println("my port: "+socket.getLocalPort());

    String line;
    BufferedReader user_input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // here starts updated code

    while(true)
    {
        if (user_input.ready())
        {
           line=user_input.readLine();

           if(line.equals("-1")) {
             break;
           }
           make_output.println(server+": "+line);
           make_output.flush();
           System.out.println("sent");
        }

         while (sin.available()>0)
         {
            System.out.println(read_input.readLine());
         }
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
  }
}


public class ClientSocketRunner {
    private static String ip="localhost";
    private static int port=1440;
    private static String client="Client";
    private static String server="Server";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        ClientSocketRunner socket_runner=new ClientSocketRunner();
        socket_runner.run();
    }

    private void run() throws Exception
    {
         Socket client_socket=new Socket(ip, port);
        OutputStream os=client_socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is=client_socket.getInputStream();

        PrintStream make_output=new PrintStream(os);
        BufferedReader read_input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        make_output.println("Hello, I'm the Client");
        System.out.println(read_input.readLine());
        System.out.println("my port: "+client_socket.getLocalPort());

       String line=null;
       BufferedReader user_input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       // here starts updated code

        while(true)
        {
            if (user_input.ready())
            {
               line=user_input.readLine();

               if(line.equals("-1")) {
                 break;
               }
               make_output.println(server+": "+line);
               make_output.flush();
               System.out.println("sent");
            }

             while (is.available()>0)
             {
                System.out.println(read_input.readLine());
             }
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, I'll try it out. Was going to look into threads myself after this simplified version. But to me my code doesn't work. Exactly for multiple lines! The first line arrives, but the others arrive later through some magic...